# Ask about how to create data entry form directly on the sheet of google sheet

Tags: javascript

Ask about how to create data entry form directly on the sheet of google sheet

I want to create a data entry form directly on Google Sheet, in which the "FA" Sheet is the Sheet containing Form and "D" Sheet is the Data Sheet, You can see the file attached and help me, Thank
Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17nLFtT7sVkDQfYzrGo4TJfVniQ53gqT_hfACPYljZFQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can you include the input and output you want to your shared spreadsheet? It will help users think of your solution.

Comment: I edited the spreadsheet, went to see it and helped me ... Thank you...Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17nLFtT7sVkDQfYzrGo4TJfVniQ53gqT_hfACPYljZFQ/edit?usp=sharing